# How to add a switch in Xamarin Shell MenuItem

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to have a switch in a menuItem of my AppShell.xaml (in addition to the usual text and icon). How can I do that while keeping the styles of the MenuItem ?

I used a DataTemplate in the Shell.MenuItemTemplate of my MenuItem but the result is just ugly as all the styles of the MenuItem are lost. The MenuItem created this way does not have the same font, text color, and font size than the other FlyoutItems and MenuItems of the Shell.

```
<MenuItem Text="MyMenuItem" Command="{Binding SwitchMode}">
    <Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Label Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                <Switch IsToggled="{Binding IsModeActivated}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.MenuItemTemplate>
```

Comment: If you remove the switch it works as expected with the current code?

Comment: No the switch is not the problem. It's the fact that I use a DataTemplate that makes me to have to redefine all the styles. That's normal I think but I am looking for a way to find be able to keep the styles of a MenuItem of reuse them

Answer (score 4):

Use element `Shell.MenuItemTemplate` with reference to `DataTemplate` defined in `Resources`.

Common/shared element property values can be defined in a `"BaseStyle"`, while menu specific properties can be defined in styles based on the `"BaseStyle"`:

```
<Shell.Resources>
  ...
  <Style x:Key="labelBaseStyle" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center" />
  </Style>

  <Style x:Key="firstMenuLabelStyle" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource labelBaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Italic" />
  </Style>

  <Style x:Key="menuLabelStyle" TargetType="Label" BasedOn="{StaticResource labelBaseStyle}">
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
  </Style>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="firstMenuItemTemplate">
    <StackLayout ...
      <Label Style="{StaticResource firstMenuLabelStyle}" ...
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="menuItemTemplate">
    <StackLayout ...
      <Label Style="{StaticResource menuLabelStyle}" ...
  </DataTemplate>
  ...
</Shell.Resources>
...
<MenuItem Text="MenuItem1" Shell.MenuItemTemplate="{StaticResource firstMenuItemTemplate}" />

<MenuItem Text="MenuItem2" Shell.MenuItemTemplate="{StaticResource menuItemTemplate}" />
```

Comment: Your answer was not accepted but I just wanted to comment that this was extremely helpful for me - thank you @Benl